# Multiple kernel calls in CUDA

Tags: c, parallel-processing, cuda, cuda-streams

I'm trying to call the same kernel on CUDA (with one different input parameter) more times, but it executes only the first one and doesn't follow with other kernel calls.
Assume the inputs arrays are 
`new_value0=[123.814935276; 234; 100; 166; 203.0866414; 383; 186; 338; 173.0984233]` and 
`new_value1=[186.221113; 391; 64; 235; 195.7454998; 275; 218; 121; 118.0333872]`
part of output is:

```
entra
entra
entra
334 
549 
524 
alpha1.000000 
alpha1.000000 
alpha1.000000 
in 2 idx-j 0-0 Value 123.814934 - m=334 - k=0 
 mlx -1618.175171 
in 1 idx-j 0-1 Value 234.000000 - m=334 k=1 
 mlx -571.983032 
in 1 idx-j 0-2 Value 100.000000 - m=334 k=2 
 mlx -208.243652 
in 1 idx-j 1-0 Value 166.000000 - m=549 k=3 
 mlx 477.821777 
in 2 idx-j 1-1 Value 203.086639 - m=549 - k=4 
 mlx -2448.556396 
in 1 idx-j 1-2 Value 383.000000 - m=549 k=5 
 mlx -549.565674 
in 1 idx-j 2-0 Value 186.000000 - m=524 k=6 
 mlx 239.955444 
in 1 idx-j 2-1 Value 338.000000 - m=524 k=7 
 mlx 1873.975708 
in 2 idx-j 2-2 Value 173.098419 - m=524 - k=8 
 mlx -835.600220 
mlx =-835.600220 
bs = -835.600220 .
esci
esci
esci
```

It is from the first kernel call.

This is the kernel:

```
__global__  void calculateMLpa( int N, float *bs, float *Value, float alphaxixj, float tauxi, const int sz, int dim, int *m){
    int idx = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
    printf("entra\n");
    if(idx<N){
        bs[idx]=0;
        int i,k=0;
        float mlx = 0;
        float v;
        float alphaxi;
        m[idx]=0;

        int state[9];
        int p, j, t;
        int cont=0;


        if(idx==0){
            m[idx]=Value[idx+1]+Value[idx+2];
        }
        else if(idx==1){
            m[idx]=Value[idx+2]+Value[idx+4];
        }else{
            m[idx]=Value[idx+4]+Value[idx+5];
        }
        printf("%d \n",m[idx]);

        alphaxi = alphaxixj * (((float) sz) - 1.0);
        alphaxi = alphaxixj;
        printf("alpha%f \n",alphaxi);
        if(idx==0){
            for(i=0;i<sz;i++){
                for (j = 0; j < sz; j++) {
                    // xi!=xj
                    if (i!=j){
                        if(j==0) {
                            k=i*3;
                        }
                        else if(j==1){
                            k=i*3+1;
                        }
                        else if(j==2) {
                            k=i*3+2;
                        }
                        mlx = mlx + lgamma(alphaxixj + Value[k]) - lgamma(alphaxixj);
                        printf("in 1 idx-j %d-%d Value %f - m=%d k=%d \n",i,j,Value[k],m[i],k);
                        printf(" mlx %f \n",mlx);
                        //k++;
                    }
                    // xi
                    else {
                        if(j==0) {
                            k=i*3;
                        }
                        else if(j==1){
                            k=i*3+1;
                        }
                        else if(j==2) {
                            k=i*3+2;
                        }
                        mlx = mlx + lgamma(alphaxi) - lgamma(alphaxi + m[i]);
                        mlx = mlx + lgamma(alphaxi + m[i] + 1.0)+ (alphaxi + 1.0) * log(tauxi);
                        mlx = mlx - lgamma(alphaxi + 1.0)- (alphaxi + m[i] + 1.0) * log(tauxi + Value[k]);
                        printf("in 2 idx-j %d-%d Value %f - m=%d - k=%d \n",i,j,Value[k],m[i],k);
                        printf(" mlx %f \n",mlx);
                        //k++;
                    }
                }
            }

            printf("mlx =%f \n",mlx);
            bs[idx]=mlx;
            printf("bs = %f .\n",bs[idx]);
        }
    }
    printf("esci\n");
}
```

Here is the code:

```
int main (void){
    printf("START");
    FILE *pf;
    const int N=9;
    char fName[2083];
    char *parents[3]={"0","1","2"};
    char *traject[9]={"0-0","0-1","0-2","1-0","1-1","1-2","2-0","2-1","2-2"};
    size_t parents_len;
    size_t traject_len;
    parents_len=sizeof(char)/sizeof(parents[0]);
    traject_len=sizeof(char)/sizeof(traject[0]);
    //possibile malloc

    //pointer host to memory
    char **parents_dev;
    char **traject_dev;

    //allocate on device
    cudaMalloc((void **)&parents_dev,sizeof(char**)*parents_len);
    cudaMalloc((void **)&traject_dev,sizeof(char**)*traject_len);

    //host to Device
    cudaMemcpy(parents_dev,parents,sizeof(char**)*parents_len,cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    cudaMemcpy(traject_dev,traject,sizeof(char**)*traject_len,cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);

    //Loop start
    int file,Epoca;

    float *bs;
    float *bs_dev;
    int file_size0=28;
    int file_size1=55;
    int file_size3=109;
    //size_t size = N * sizeof(float);
    bs=(float *)malloc(N * sizeof(float));
    cudaMalloc((void **)&bs_dev, N * sizeof(float));


    float *new_value0,*new_value0_dev;
    new_value0=(float *)malloc(file_size0*N/3);
    cudaMalloc((void **)&new_value0_dev, N * file_size0/3);
    //
    float *new_value1,*new_value1_dev;
    new_value1=(float *)malloc(file_size0*N/3);
    cudaMalloc((void **)&new_value1_dev, N * file_size0/3);
    //
    float *new_value2,*new_value2_dev;
    new_value2=(float *)malloc(file_size0*N/3);
    cudaMalloc((void **)&new_value2_dev, N * file_size0/3);
    //
    //one parent 1,2
    float *new_value00,*new_value00_dev;
    new_value00=(float *)malloc(file_size1*N/6);
    cudaMalloc((void **)&new_value00_dev, N * file_size1/6);
    //
    float *new_value01,*new_value01_dev;
    new_value01=(float *)malloc(file_size1*N/6);
    cudaMalloc((void **)&new_value01_dev, N * file_size1/6);
    //
    float *new_value10,*new_value10_dev;
    new_value10=(float *)malloc(file_size1*N/6);
    cudaMalloc((void **)&new_value10_dev, N * file_size1/6);
    //
    float *new_value11,*new_value11_dev;
    new_value11=(float *)malloc(file_size1*N/6);
    cudaMalloc((void **)&new_value11_dev, N * file_size1/6);
    //
    float *new_value20,*new_value20_dev;
    new_value20=(float *)malloc(file_size1*N/6);
    cudaMalloc((void **)&new_value20_dev, N * file_size1/6);
    //
    float *new_value21,*new_value21_dev;
    new_value21=(float *)malloc(file_size1*N/6);
    cudaMalloc((void **)&new_value21_dev, N * file_size1/6);
    //
    //double parent
    float *new_value000,*new_value000_dev;
    new_value000=(float *)malloc(file_size3*N/12);
    cudaMalloc((void **)&new_value000_dev, N * file_size3/12);
    //
    float *new_value001,*new_value001_dev;
    new_value001=(float *)malloc(file_size3*N/12);
    cudaMalloc((void **)&new_value001_dev, N * file_size3/12);
    //
    float *new_value010,*new_value010_dev;
    new_value010=(float *)malloc(file_size3*N/12);
    cudaMalloc((void **)&new_value010_dev, N * file_size3/12);
    //
    float *new_value011,*new_value011_dev;
    new_value011=(float *)malloc(file_size3*N/12);
    cudaMalloc((void **)&new_value011_dev, N * file_size3/12);
    //
    float *new_value100,*new_value100_dev;
    new_value100=(float *)malloc(file_size3*N/12);
    cudaMalloc((void **)&new_value100_dev, N * file_size3/12);
    //
    float *new_value101,*new_value101_dev;
    new_value101=(float *)malloc(file_size3*N/12);
    cudaMalloc((void **)&new_value101_dev, N * file_size3/12);
    //
    float *new_value110,*new_value110_dev;
    new_value110=(float *)malloc(file_size3*N/12);
    cudaMalloc((void **)&new_value110_dev, N * file_size3/12);
    //
    float *new_value111,*new_value111_dev;
    new_value111=(float *)malloc(file_size3*N/12);
    cudaMalloc((void **)&new_value111_dev, N * file_size3/12);
    //
    float *new_value200,*new_value200_dev;
    new_value200=(float *)malloc(file_size3*N/12);
    cudaMalloc((void **)&new_value200_dev, N * file_size3/12);
    //
    float *new_value201,*new_value201_dev;
    new_value201=(float *)malloc(file_size3*N/12);
    cudaMalloc((void **)&new_value201_dev, N * file_size3/12);
    //
    float *new_value210,*new_value210_dev;
    new_value210=(float *)malloc(file_size3*N/12);
    cudaMalloc((void **)&new_value210_dev, N * file_size3/12);
    //
    float *new_value211,*new_value211_dev;
    new_value211=(float *)malloc(file_size3*N/12);
    cudaMalloc((void **)&new_value211_dev, N * file_size3/12);
    //int file;
    for(file=0;file<4;file++){
        int f, i, j, file_size=0, kk=0;
        //file IO
        sprintf(fName, "//home//user//prova%d.csv",file);
        pf=fopen(fName,"r");
        char *X;
        char *PaX;
        int Time;
        char *pa;
        char *xixj;
        float val;
        char buffer[BUFSIZ], *ptr;
        if (pf)
        {

            /*
             * Read each line from the file.
             */
            while(fgets(buffer, sizeof buffer, pf)){
                file_size++;
            }
            fclose(pf);
        }
        //variabile per kernel
        float *Value, *Value_dev;
        Value=(float *)malloc(file_size*N);
        cudaMalloc((void **)&Value_dev, N * file_size);

        //

        pf=fopen(fName,"r");
        if(pf)
        {
            printf("\nnumero righe file %d = %d\n",file,file_size);
            char *state[file_size];
            while(fgets(buffer, sizeof buffer, pf))
            {
                //printf("start csv \n");
                char *token;
                char *ptr = buffer;
                const char end[2]=",";//fgets(buffer, sizeof buffer, pf);
                token = strtok(ptr, end);
                f=0;
                /* walk through other tokens */
                while( token != NULL )
                {

                    if(f==0){
                        X=token;
                        //  printf( "X %s\n", token );
                    }else if(f==1){
                        PaX=token;
                        //  printf( "PaX %s\n", token );
                    }
                    else if(f==2){
                        Time=strtod(token,NULL);
                        //  printf( "Time %f \n", token );

                    }
                    else if(f==3){
                        pa=token;
                        //  printf( "pa %s \n", token );

                    }
                    else if(f==4){
                        xixj=(token);
                        //  printf( "xixj %s \n", token );

                    }
                    else{
                        Value[kk]=strtod(&token[1], NULL);
                        //          printf("Value %f \n", Value[kk]);
                        kk++;

                    }
                    token = strtok(NULL, end);
                    f++;

                }

            }

            //

            //insert in variable
            if (file==0){
                for (i=0;i<(file_size0-1)/3;++i){
                    new_value0[i]=Value[i+1];
                    cudaMemcpy(new_value0_dev,new_value0,N*sizeof(file_size0), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
                    new_value1[i]=Value[i + 1+((file_size0-1)/3)];
                    cudaMemcpy(new_value1_dev,new_value1,N*sizeof(file_size0), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
                    new_value2[i]=Value[i + (1+ 2*(file_size0-1)/3)];
                    cudaMemcpy(new_value2_dev,new_value2,N*sizeof(file_size0), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
                    //  printf(" new_value- %d - %f - %f - %f \n",i,new_value0[i],new_value1[i],new_value2[i]);


                }
            }else if(file==1 || file==2){
                for (i=0; i<(file_size1-1)/6;++i)
                {
                    new_value00[i]=Value[i+1];
                    cudaMemcpy(new_value00_dev,new_value00,N*sizeof(file_size0), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
                    new_value01[i]=Value[i+ ((file_size0-1)/3)+1];
                    cudaMemcpy(new_value01_dev,new_value01,N*sizeof(file_size1), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
                    new_value10[i]=Value[i+ (2*(file_size1-1)/6)+1];
                    cudaMemcpy(new_value10_dev,new_value10,N*sizeof(file_size1), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
                    new_value11[i]=Value[i+ (3*(file_size1-1)/6)+1];
                    cudaMemcpy(new_value11_dev,new_value11,N*sizeof(file_size1), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
                    new_value20[i]=Value[i+ (4*(file_size1-1)/6)+1];
                    cudaMemcpy(new_value20_dev,new_value20,N*sizeof(file_size1), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
                    new_value21[i]=Value[i+ (5*(file_size1-1)/6)+1];
                    cudaMemcpy(new_value21_dev,new_value21,N*sizeof(file_size1), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
                    //      printf(" new_value- %d - %f - %f - %f - %f - %f - %f \n",i,new_value00[i],new_value01[i],new_value10[i],new_value11[i],new_value20[i],new_value21[i]);

                }
            }else{
                for (i=0; i<(file_size3-1)/12;++i)
                {
                    new_value000[i]=Value[i+1];
                    cudaMemcpy(new_value000_dev,new_value000,N*sizeof(file_size3), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
                    new_value001[i]=Value[i+ ((file_size3-1)/12)+1];
                    cudaMemcpy(new_value001_dev,new_value001,N*sizeof(file_size3), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
                    new_value010[i]=Value[i+ (2*(file_size3-1)/12)+1];
                    cudaMemcpy(new_value010_dev,new_value010,N*sizeof(file_size3), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
                    new_value011[i]=Value[i+ (3*(file_size3-1)/12)+1];
                    cudaMemcpy(new_value011_dev,new_value011,N*sizeof(file_size3), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
                    new_value100[i]=Value[i+ (4*(file_size3-1)/12)+1];
                    cudaMemcpy(new_value100_dev,new_value100,N*sizeof(file_size3), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
                    new_value101[i]=Value[i+ (5*(file_size3-1)/12)+1];
                    cudaMemcpy(new_value101_dev,new_value101,N*sizeof(file_size3), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
                    new_value110[i]=Value[i+ (6*(file_size3-1)/12)+1];
                    cudaMemcpy(new_value110_dev,new_value110,N*sizeof(file_size3), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
                    new_value111[i]=Value[i+ (7*(file_size3-1)/12)+1];
                    cudaMemcpy(new_value111_dev,new_value111,N*sizeof(file_size3), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
                    new_value200[i]=Value[i+ (8*(file_size3-1)/12)+1];
                    cudaMemcpy(new_value200_dev,new_value200,N*sizeof(file_size3), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
                    new_value201[i]=Value[i+ (9*(file_size3-1)/12)+1];
                    cudaMemcpy(new_value201_dev,new_value201,N*sizeof(file_size3), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
                    new_value210[i]=Value[i+ (10*(file_size3-1)/12)+1];
                    cudaMemcpy(new_value210_dev,new_value210,N*sizeof(file_size3), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
                    new_value211[i]=Value[i+ (11*(file_size3-1)/12)+1];
                    cudaMemcpy(new_value211_dev,new_value211,N*sizeof(file_size3), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
                    //  printf(" new_value- %d - %f - %f - %f - %f - %f - %f - %f - %f - %f - %f - %f - %f \n",i,new_value000[i],new_value001[i],new_value010[i],new_value011[i],new_value100[i],new_value101[i],new_value110[i],new_value111[i],new_value200[i],new_value201[i],new_value210[i],new_value211[i]);

                }

            }
        }
    }
    //cudaMemcpy(Value_dev,Value,N*sizeof(file_size), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);

    //variable of kernel
    //no parent


    //START computation
    printf("\nPRE KERNEL\n");

    const int sz=(sizeof(parents)/sizeof(*(parents)));
    const int dim=(sizeof(traject)/sizeof(*(traject)));
    printf("%d - %d \n",sz, dim);

    //chiamata kernel

    int block_size = 3;
    int n_blocks =1 ;
    int *m, *m_dev;
    m=(int *)malloc(sz*N);
    cudaMalloc((void **)&m_dev, N * sz);

    float *trns_dev;
    cudaMalloc((void **)&trns_dev, N * dim);
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<(file_size0-1)/3;i++){
        printf(" new_value- %d - %f - %f - %f \n",i,new_value0[i],new_value1[i],new_value2[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
    for(i=0;i<(file_size1-1)/6;i++){
        printf(" new_value- %d - %f - %f - %f - %f - %f - %f \n",i,new_value00[i],new_value01[i],new_value10[i],new_value11[i],new_value20[i],new_value21[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
    for(i=0;i<(file_size3-1)/12;i++){
        printf(" new_value- %d - %f - %f - %f - %f - %f - %f - %f - %f - %f - %f - %f - %f \n",i,new_value000[i],new_value001[i],new_value010[i],new_value011[i],new_value100[i],new_value101[i],new_value110[i],new_value111[i],new_value200[i],new_value201[i],new_value210[i],new_value211[i]);
    }

    for(Epoca=0; Epoca<3; Epoca++){
        bs=0;
        float bf=0;
        cudaMalloc((void **)&bf, N * sz);
        cudaMemcpy(bs_dev,bs,N*sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
        if(Epoca==0){

            calculateMLpa<<<n_blocks, block_size >>>(N,bs_dev,new_value0_dev,1.0,0.1,sz,dim,m_dev);
            cudaDeviceSynchronize();
            cudaMemcpy(bs,bs_dev,N*sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
            cudaMemcpy(m,m_dev,N*sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
            bf =+ bs[0];
            printf("score= %f m0 = %d, m1 = %d, m2 = %d \n\n", bf, m[0], m[1], m[2]);

            calculateMLpa<<<n_blocks, block_size >>>(N,bs_dev,new_value00_dev,1.0,0.1,sz,dim,m_dev);
            cudaDeviceSynchronize();
            cudaMemcpy(bs,bs_dev,N*sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
            cudaMemcpy(m,m_dev,N*sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
            bf =+ bs[0];
            printf("score= %f \n", bf);


        }

        printf("score %d= %f \n",Epoca, bf);

    }

    free(bs_dev);

}
```

I think that I can parallelize this with stream but I have never used it before. I have watched [this](http://on-demand.gputechconf.com/gtc-express/2011/presentations/StreamsAndConcurrencyWebinar.pdf) for start.

Comment: I don't understand what your question is here. Can you explain for clearly what you want to know?

Comment: @talonmies how can I execute two kernel, and if it's possible, to parallelize the execution (note: in this example there are only 2 kernel, but in the program are more)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you should use parallel [CUDA streams](http://devblogs.nvidia.com/parallelforall/gpu-pro-tip-cuda-7-streams-simplify-concurrency/).

An interesting option:

> CUDA 7 introduces a new option, the per-thread default stream, that
>   has two effects. First, it gives each host thread its own default
>   stream. This means that commands issued to the default stream by
>   different host threads can run concurrently.

Also noteworthy:

> As described by the CUDA C Programming Guide, asynchronous commands
>   return control to the calling host thread before the device has
>   finished the requested task (they are non-blocking). These commands
>   are:
>
> Kernel launches; Memory copies between two addresses to the same
>   device memory; Memory copies from host to device of a memory block of
>   64 KB or less; Memory copies performed by functions with the Async
>   suffix; Memory set function calls.